# Are all LFF caddies compatible in a LFF slot?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware

Is it possible to use, let's say, some Chembro LFF caddies on a HP gen8 server or a Dell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Turns out you can't have a 3 character answer.